# F# function overloading with same parameter number

Tags: f#

I have a simple F# function `cost` receiving a single parameter `amount` which is used for some calculations. It is a `float` so I need to pass in something like `cost 33.0` which in math is the same as `cost 33`. The compiler complaints about it, and I understand why, but I would like being able to call it like that, I tried to create another function named the same and used type annotation for both of them and I also get compiler warnings. Is there a way to do this like C# does?

Comment: What would be (ideally) the return type of your cost function? Always a float, the same as the input or another type? That's a small detail but it may define which way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two mechanisms in F# to achieve this, and both do not rely on implicit casts "like C#":

(A) Method overloading

```
 type Sample =
     static member cost (amount: float) =
         amount |> calculations
     static member cost (amount: int) =
         (amount |> float) |> calculations

 Sample.cost 10   // compiles OK
 Sample.cost 10.  // compiles OK
```

(B) [Using inlining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx)

```
let inline cost amount =
    amount + amount

cost 10   // compiles OK
cost 10.  // compiles OK
```

Comment: inlining will not work if the cost function use some float literal for example `let inline cost amount = amount * 2. // val inline cost: float -> float`

Comment: @Sehnsucht, there are special primitives for use within generic functions. Check `LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne`.

Comment: @bytebuster sure I know, my point was more to say just adding `inline` in front of the name can't always be enough. there are `GenericOne` and `GenericZero` we can even do some things using `AdditionDynamic` and so on but that requires a lot of changes.

Comment: @Sehnsucht: These extremely simplistic snippets illustrating use of *(A)run-time polymorphism* vs. *(B)compile-time generics* were supposed to give a starting point for further research. Specific techniques for (B) can be found, for example, in [Expert F# 3.0](http://www.apress.com/9781430246503).

Answer (score 2):

F# doesn't allow overloading of let-bound functions, but you can overload methods on classes like in C#.

Sometimes, you can [change the model to work on a Discriminated Union](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/21/replace-overloading-with-discriminated-unions) instead of a set of overloaded primitives, but I don't think it would be particularly sensible to do just to be able to distinguish between floats and integers.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use an int at call site but have a float inside the function body ; why not simply cast it ?

```
let cost amount =
  // cast amount from to float (reusing the name amount to shadow the first one)
  let amount = float amount
  // rest of your function
```

Comment: i want to be able to use both, sometimes it can be something like `38.6`, it's just for to make it easier when it is not (like when it is `39.0` say)

Comment: @Luiso in F# type system ; `33` and `33.` (note the dot) are not the same thing and are not interchangeable. If you want the latter you can't write the former alone and expect the code to guess what you really mean.